# firestore database validation on type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Anyone know how to validate base on `instanceof`?

This seems like a no brainer check but I cannot find reference for this type of validation in the docs and my attempts have not been correct.

I want to fail if the value is not a `Date`. It might be a `Timestamp` in the current version of firestore.

**Failed attempts**

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.date instanceof Date;
allow write: if request.resource.data.date instanceof Timestamp;
allow write: if !!Timestamp(request.resource.data.date);
allow write: if !!rules.Timestamp(request.resource.data.date);
allow write: if !!rules.Timestamp.date(request.data.date);
allow write: if !!Timestamp.date(request.data.date);
allow write: if !!Timestamp(request.data.date);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was clued into the solution through firebase support. The key comparator is the `is` keyword.

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.date is timestamp;
```

Comment: Any documentation? What do I type for GeoPoint for example?

Comment: Still no docs over a year later. Pretty much no examples on the web. Weak point of firebase for sure. Have you found any more help on the subject?

Comment: The only official "documentation" source I can find for type check is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbd_4LT0Y4s (at about the 11:00 mark)

Comment: If you use the wrong when defining the security rules it lists the available types in the error message, which might find useful. So I'll leave it here: bool,bytes,constraint,duration,float,int,latlng,list,set,number,map,string,timestamp,path,map_diff